# injecting different implementations and configurations of same interface into different clients

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Suppose I have an interface `IStorage` and multiple implementations of it, e.g.:

```
class FileStorage : IStorage
{
    public FileStorage(string filePath)
    {            
    }
}

class HttpStorage : Storage
{
    public HttpStorage(IHttpClient httpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I have multiple classes that I want to register in my application and each of them needs a different `IStorage` instance.

- All instances of `ClassA` (implementing and registered via `IClassA`) need a singleton `FileStorage` with *"C:\Temp\foo.txt"* as `filePath`.
- All instances of `ClassB` (implementing and registered via `IClassB`)  need a singleton `FileStorage` with *"C:\Temp\bar.txt"* as `filePath`.
- All instances of `ClassC` (implementing and registered via `IClassC`)  need a singleton `HttpStorage` with the registered singleton of `IHttpClient`.

How can I achieve the above without falling back to creating most of the  dependency graph manually?

Comment: Note that I updated my answer. Your use case has been simplified with the new `RegisterConditional` overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary question to ask every time you think you need this is: Do I violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You are breaking the LSP in case the implementations aren't interchangeable for one another. If `ClassA` breaks when you inject an `HttpStorage` into it, you are breaking the LSP. In that case, you should give each implementation each own abstraction, such as `IFileStorage` and `IHttpStorage`.

My first impression is that you are not violating LSP. Simple Injector v3 contains a `RegisterConditional` method that allows you to do conditional registrations. With Simple Injector v3.1 you can make the registration as follows:

```
Lifestyle transient = Lifestyle.Transient;

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IStorage),
    transient.CreateRegistration(() => new FileStorage(@"C:\Temp\foo.txt"), container),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(ClassA));

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IStorage),
    transient.CreateRegistration(() => new FileStorage(@"C:\Temp\bar.txt"), container),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(ClassB));

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IStorage),
    transient.CreateRegistration(() => new HttpStorage(new HttpClient()), container),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(ClassC));
```

The `RegisterConditional` overload that accepts an `Registration` instance is new in v3.1.